# How to make an active job in ruby on rails to read json file then transfer data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

I'm newbie here.
I have problem, I build a web use Ruby on Rails.
I want to get data from json file and then insert into database.
data in json file can be increased at any time. So I should have a background job to run in certain intervals.
I have read in Ruby documentation, and it said that I can use Active Job.
But I still confuse to do that.
What should I do step by step to make it real? or you guys can give me example?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: are you using linux based OS for rails development?

Comment: Check my answer for using ActiveJob, see documentation for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ActiveJob**

Active Job Setup

The Active Job adapter must be set to **:sidekiq** or it will simply use the default :inline.

This can be done in **config/application.rb** like this:

For example:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # ...
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

Next, generate Job:

```
rails generate job Example
```

Sample JSON Data:

```
{
    "title"  :    "Ruby In Rails",
    "url"    :    "http://rubyinrails.com",
    "posts"  :    {
                    "1":"strftime-time-format-in-ruby",
                    "2":"what-is-gemset"
                  }
}
```

Will creates /app/jobs/example_job.rb

```
class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Set the Queue as Default
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    # Perform Job
    require 'json'

    # Open JSON File
    root = Rails.root.to_s       
    file = File.read('#{root}/data.json')


    # Parse Data from File
    data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

    # Do the SAVING and validation HERE...
    test = Sample.new
    test.title = data_hash['title']
    ......
    test.save


  end
end
```

Usage, ex. in Controller:

```
ExampleJob.perform_later args
```

[Documentations Here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job)

Or if you prefer to **USE** **CRONJOB** for that function:

For example make a file named "**save_json.rb**" inside **lib/tasks/** in your Rails Application.

Code:

```
namespace :save_json do
  desc "..."
  task :execute => :environment do
    require 'json'

    # Open JSON File
    root = Rails.root.to_s       
    file = File.read('#{root}/data.json')


    #Parse Data from File
    data_hash = JSON.parse(file) 

    #Getting DATA

    data_hash['title']
     => "Ruby In Rails"
    data_hash.keys
     => ["title", "url", "posts"]
    data_hash['posts']
     => { "1" => "strftime-time-format-in-ruby", "2" => "what-is-gemset" }

    # Do the SAVING and validation HERE...
    test = Sample.new
    test.title = data_hash['title']
    ......
    test.save

end
```

**Set Background Job function in crontab**.

```
vi /etc/crontab
```

Code:
For example **every minute**....

```
*/1 * * * * cd /my_rails_app && bundle exec rake save_json:execute
```

Comment: Thank you. I use :inline and it's very easy to use. Thanks.